# Python using threading.Event()

Tags: python, multithreading, event-handling

I have two threads that are accessing a web service. One thread is updating a resource and other is possibly getting them.

My webservice class looks below:

```
class WebServiceHandler(object):
    RESOURCE_URL='/Resource/{0}'
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self._http_connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, port)

    def update(self, id, resource):
        url = self.RESOURCE_URL.format(id)
        self._http_connection.request('POST', url,
                                      resource)
        response = self._http_connection.getresponse()
        response_body = response.read()

    def get(self, id):
        url = self.RESOURCE_URL.format(id)
        self._http_connection.request('GET', url)
        response = self._http_connection.getresponse()
        response_body = response.read()
        return response_body
```

I want to make sure before get is accessed, update is called.I was using threading.Event() to synchronize inside update() and get().

```
class WebServiceHandler(object):
    RESOURCE_URL='/Resource/{0}'
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self._http_connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, port)
        self._update_event = threading.Event()

    def update(id, resource):
        url = self.RESOURCE_URL.format(id)
        self._http_connection.request('POST', url,
                                      resource)
        response = self._http_connection.getresponse()
        response_body = response.read()
        self._update_event.set()
    def get(id):
        self._update_event.wait()
        self._update_event.clear()
        url = self.RESOURCE_URL.format(id)
        self._http_connection.request('GET', url)
        response = self._http_connection.getresponse()
        response_body = response.read()
```

But somehow when I have two thread update() and get(), update() transaction is successful but get() does not return, it stuck there waiting.

```
test1 = WebServiceHandler('localhost', 80)
import time

def step1():        
    time.sleep(4)
    test1.update('10', {'resource_name': 'chef agent' })
    print "updated!!"

def step2():        
    print test1.get('10')

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=step1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=step2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print "Done!!"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code that's actually calling `update` and `get`?

Comment: This code looks fine, and works fine on my system when I remove the http request pieces (so all I'm testing is the `Event`). Is this the actual code you're using? I'm guessing no, because `get` and `update` are missing `self` arguments.

Comment: Good catch Dano! Yes it is pretty muc hthe same code, except I needed to type. somehow SO does not let me copy-pasting from my pycharm.

Comment: In that case, are you sure you're getting stuck waiting on the `Event` inside of `get`? Is it possible the HTTP request is hanging?

Comment: I agree with dano, it must be some side effect of the code, the sync mechanism seems fine. Check if `getresponse` is returning correctly.