# Can I call a thread recurrently from within a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I'm trying to transfer samples from thread A ("Acquisition") to thread B ("P300") using `queue` but I can't read any data in thread B, although samples **are** being allocated in thread A. Judging by my output, I think my thread B is rushing and testing things before my thread A starts to put data in.

See an approximation of my code structure bellow:

```
import threading
import queue
from queue import Empty
import numpy as np
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("error")

class AcqThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dataOutQ1, dataOutQ2, stopQ1, stopQ2, saveQ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopQ2 = stopQ2
        self.stopQ1 = stopQ1
        self.dataOutQ2 = dataOutQ2
        self.dataOutQ1 = dataOutQ1
        self.saveQ = saveQ

    def run(self):
        Acquisition(inlet, self.dataOutQ1, self.dataOutQ2, self.stopQ1, self.stopQ2, self.saveQ)

class P300Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dataInQ, featureQ, stopQ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dataInQ = dataInQ
        self.featureQ = featureQ
        self.stopQ = stopQ

    def run(self):
        P300fun(self.dataInQ, self.featureQ, self.stopQ)

threadLock = threading.Lock()
SaveQ = queue.Queue()
DataOutQ1 = queue.Queue()
DataOutQ2 = queue.Queue()
StopQ1 = queue.Queue()
StopQ2 = queue.Queue()
FeatQ1 = queue.Queue()
StopQ1.put(0)
StopQ2.put(0)
#
AcqTh = AcqThread(DataOutQ1, DataOutQ2, StopQ1, StopQ2, SaveQ)
P300Th = P300Thread(DataOutQ1, FeatQ1, StopQ1)

def Acquisition(inlet, dataOutQ1, dataOutQ2, stopQ1, stopQ2, saveQ):
    i = 0
    print('Starting...')
    while i<1250: #i is the number of samples
        sample, timestamp = inlet.pull_sample() #samples coming in @ 250Hz
        ##Normalization, filtering##
        threadLock.acquire()
        dataOutQ1.put([filtsamples[:,-250:], rawtimestamps[-250:]]) #I only need the last 250 samples
        threadLock.release()
        i += 1

def P300fun(dataInQ, featureQ, stopQ):
    p300sample = []
    p300timestamp = []
    print(f"Is DataInQ size true? {DataOutQ1.qsize()}")
    print("Is dataInQ emtpy?", DataOutQ1.empty())
    while dataInQ.qsize(): #or while not dataqueue.empty():
        try:
            print("DataInQ has data")
            ss, ts = dataInQ.get(0) 
            print('<>P300\n>>Samples [', ss, ']\nTimestamp [', ts, ']')
        except Empty:
            return
    print('Thread Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Looking for an EEG stream...')
    streams = resolve_stream('type', 'EEG')
    inlet = StreamInlet(streams[0])
    print('Connected!\n')

    AcqTh.start()
    P300Th.start()

    AcqTh.join()
    P300Th.join()

    print("\n\n>>>DONE<<<\n\n")
```

And output:

```
Looking for an EEG stream...
Connected!

Is DataInQ size true? 0
Starting...
Is dataInQ emtpy? True
Thread Finished

>>>DONE<<<
```

In my research, [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331297/python-multiprocessing-queue-is-empty-although-it-is-filled-in-a-different-threa) appeared to present a similar problem, but it seems that the problem was in the image processing part (and they use the `multiprocessing` package). [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502147/queue-in-main-thread-is-empty-after-adding-to-it-from-worker-thread) seems to have a concurrency problem, which might be my problem, but I'm not sure how to translate it to my problemlet me know if I'm wrong, tho). [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098465/python-multithreaded-queue-remaining-empty) had just a problem with the order of arguments, so not applicable here, I think.

How should I go about this? Should I recurrently call thread B from within thread A?? Do I need a loop or a delay on thread B? Is there some issue with the `.join()` part maybe? I'll need to add more threads in a near future, so it would be good to figure out how to work with only two first...

All help is appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a noob can be tricky... So I'll answer my own question to help other beginners that may come across this issue too.

Well, first things first: no, it's not possible to call a thread from within a thread recurrently, because each thread can only be called once.

But there is a way to prevent the thread from ending, making them wait for triggers that will allow them to continue. After some more research, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508719/python-using-threading-event) that showed me there is a way to create events for threads. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects). And it's quite straight forward: the event objects behave like flags and can be `set()` (indicating True) or `clear()` (indicating False, which is the original value). To test an event, one can use the `is_set()` method for boolean problems or use the `wait()` method instead of a timer. In my case, it saved me some queues I was going to use:

```
import threading
import queue
from queue import Empty
import numpy as np


class AcqThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dataOutQ1, dataOutQ2, saveQ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dataOutQ2 = dataOutQ2
        self.dataOutQ1 = dataOutQ1
        self.saveQ = saveQ

    def run(self):
        Acquisition(inlet, self.dataOutQ1, self.dataOutQ2, self.saveQ)

class P300Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dataInQ, featureQ):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dataInQ = dataInQ
        self.featureQ = featureQ

    def run(self):
        P300fun(self.dataInQ, self.featureQ)

threadLock = threading.Lock()
SaveQ = queue.Queue()
DataOutQ1 = queue.Queue()
DataOutQ2 = queue.Queue()
FeatQ1 = queue.Queue()
FeatQ2 = queue.Queue()

#NEW:: initializes Events
E = threading.Event()
EP300 = threading.Event()
#
AcqTh = AcqThread(DataOutQ1, DataOutQ2, SaveQ)
P300Th = P300Thread(DataOutQ1, FeatQ1)
```

And it allows me to "call" thread B "recurrently", as it keeps my first while active (because of event E) and enters the processing part only when the event EP300 is set. Then, EP300 is cleared after the process is done:

```
def Acquisition(inlet, dataOutQ1, dataOutQ2 saveQ):
    i = 0
    print('Starting...')
    while i<1250:
        sample, timestamp = inlet.pull_sample()
        ##Normalization, filtering##
        if _condition_:
            threadLock.acquire()
            dataOutQ1.put([filtsamples[:,-250:], rawtimestamps[-250:]])
            threadLock.release()
            EP300.set() #NEW:: allows the P300 function to collect data from queue
        i += 1
    E.set() #NEW:: flaggs end data collection

def P300fun(dataInQ, featureQ):
    p300sample = []
    p300timestamp = []
    while not E.is_set(): #NEW:: loop until collection is ended
        if EP300.is_set(): #NEW:: activated when Event is triggered
            while dataInQ.qsize():
                try:
                    print("DataInQ has data")
                    ss, ts = dataInQ.get(0) 
                    print('<>P300\n>>Samples [', ss, ']\nTimestamp [', ts, ']')
                except Empty:
                    return
        if not E.is_set(): #NEW:: Event is cleared in case data collection is not over, waiting for a new set()
            EP300.clear()
    print('Thread Finished')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Looking for an EEG stream...')
    streams = resolve_stream('type', 'EEG')
    inlet = StreamInlet(streams[0])
    print('Connected!\n')

    AcqTh.start()
    P300Th.start()

    AcqTh.join()
    P300Th.join()

    print("\n\n>>>DONE<<<\n\n")
```